How to define AWS::Logs::LogAnomalyDetector via yml file?
I would like to define the following AWS log anomality via yml file.
I have searched the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-logs-loganomalydetector.html  , but it is not clear.
How do I define AWS log anomality for :
log group : production-xxxx-monitor 
anomality detection name : logs-anomaly-detector 
frequency : 30min

In AWS console the definition looks like :


Please show your yaml code, and provide any errors that you get.

Example to how to define AWS log anomality via yml is :
Type: AWS::Logs::LogAnomalyDetector
    Properties:
      AccountId: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      DetectorName: 'logs-anomaly-detector'
      EvaluationFrequency: 'THIRTY_MIN'
      LogGroupArnList: 
        - 'production-xxxx-monitor'

